# Creating a temporary table from inside Controller in Laravel PHP

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm making a Laravel website which is a musician directory. Every Musician has many Skills and Genres.

I want the user to be able to make advanced searches by specifying various skills and genres.

The results are then to be retrieved and sorted by relevance.

Example:

User specifies skills: "Guitar", "Theory", and genres "Jazz", "Rock", "Blues".

A Musician with the skills: "Guitar", "Bass", and genres "Jazz", "Funk" gets  a relevance score of 2 because he has two matching tags.

My plan is to make a temporary table inside of the MusiciansController `search()` function which stores all the results for the user's search.

How would I go about doing this if even possible?

Comment: you mean create temporary table in database? You can create views in mysql. refer http://www.mysqltutorial.org/create-sql-views-mysql.aspx

Comment: Hard to say without knowing table structures and example data.. i advice you to read [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) .. iám pretty sure the relevance score can be generated directly based on the user input without using anny temporary table..

Answer (score 1):

I suggest making this a little easier on yourself by designing this slightly differently.  Instead of thinking about a 'temporary' table, create an actual Laravel model and create all the functionality (calculations of relevance, user, etc) within.

By having a model / DB connection, you can also use Laravel relationships and call the methods on that model in a scalable way in future -- IE if you want to add new relevance calcs, or different relationships, you don't have to modify an SQL view - just add a method.

If you want to simulate a temporary table, just have a cleaner function at the start of the next search to wipe the previous records in the DB for that model.

Lastly, ask yourself if you even need to store this in a table, or can you calculate it using some set of formulae within the controller's methods.